# How can I calculate shipping costs before asking for shipping details

Tags: checkout, shipping, shipping-methods

Our website is based in the UK, so shipping costs are calculated based around the post code.

[image: Shipping checkout]

We would like to pretty much calculate shipping costs before they continue.

Is this possible? And can you please point me in the right direction if possible please.

Much appreciated.